# convert json response to html table from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert JSON output to HTML table and call it with AJAX, but I am not getting proper HTML table because of multidimensional array.
Below are the outputs I am getting.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$res = file_get_contents(
    'https://sphirelabs-indian-telecom-data-recharge-plans-v1.p.mashape.com/' . 
        'telecomdata/v1/get/index.php?circle=tn&opcode=idea&type=Topup', 
    false,
    $context
);
$data = json_decode($res, true);
if (count($data) > 0): 
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($data))); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $item): ?>
            <td><?= $item ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

AJAX OUTPUT :

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
Array   Array   Array   Array   Array   Array   Array   Array   Array
```

JSON response :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2602",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "10",
            "recharge_talktime": "6.9",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 10 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        },
        {
            "id": "2603",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "20",
            "recharge_talktime": "14.8",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 20 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        },
        {
            "id": "2604",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "30",
            "recharge_talktime": "23.7",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 30 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        },
        {
            "id": "2605",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "40",
            "recharge_talktime": "32.6",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 40 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        },
        {
            "id": "2606",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "50",
            "recharge_talktime": "41.5",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 50 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        },
        {
            "id": "2607",
            "operatorid": "T24",
            "circleid": "UP West",
            "recharge_amount": "100",
            "recharge_talktime": "86",
            "recharge_validity": "NA",
            "recharge_shortdesc": "Recharge of Rs 100 By T24",
            "recharge_longdesc": "Regular Recharge ",
            "recharge_type": "Topup"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think its multi array but a multidimensional array. Shouldn't it be `$data['data'] as $row` in the foreach loop?

Comment: @frz3993 - thanks..!!

Comment: In addition to @frz3993's `$data['data']` in `<?php foreach ($data['data'] as $row): ?>` it should also be `$data['data'][0]` in `<?= implode('</th><th>', array_keys($data['data'][0])); ?>`

Comment: @Sean -thanks. but if i want only `recharge_amount` row, than can i use`<?php foreach ($data['data'][1]['recharge_amount']as $row): ?>`?

Comment: Remove the `as $row` part. Just `$data['data'][1]['recharge_amount']`

Comment: `recharge_amount` is a column, not a row, so `$data['data'][1]['recharge_amount']` will only return 1 row value. Are you wanting all the `recharge_amount` values?

Comment: yes all values of `recharge_amount`

Comment: (1) change `<th><?= implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($data))); ?></th>` to just `<th>recharge_amount</th>`. (2) change `<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>` to `<?php foreach ($data['data'] as $row): ?>` . (3) change `<?php foreach ($row as $item): ?><td><?= $item ?></td><?php endforeach; ?>`  to just `<td><?= $row['recharge_amount'] ?></td>`